# Detecting send/submit button in a multi-line TextInput

Tags: react-native

The React Native [TextInput](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#content) component doesn't support the `onSubmitEditing` event if it specified as a multi-line input.

Is there a way to detect when the user presses the enter/submit/send (depending on which keyboard layout is specified) button after entering some text?

Answer (score 9):

I realize this is an old post, but I stumbled here from Google and wanted to share my solution. Because of some things that needed to happen in the case of submit, vs simply blurring, I wasn't able to use `onBlur` to interpret submit.

I utilized an `onKeyPress` listener to track the `Enter` key, and then proceeded with the submit. (**Note**, this is currently only supported in iOS [until this PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/12301) is merged.)

```
// handler
onKeyPress = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
  if (nativeEvent.key === 'Enter') {
    // submit code
  }
};

// component
<TextInput
  autoFocus={true}
  blurOnSubmit={true}
  enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
  multiline={true}
  onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
  onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress}
  returnKeyType='done'
  value={this.props.name}
/>
```

**Note, the `blurOnSubmit` is still required to prevent the return key from being passed to your `onChangeText` handler.**

Comment: onKeyPress is iOS only

Answer (score 1):

On iOS this should work according to the documentation.

Use the onBlur function:

> Callback that is called when the text input is blurred

In combination with the ios only blurOnSubmit:

> If true, the text field will blur when submitted. The default value is
>   true for single-line fields and false for multiline fields. Note that
>   for multiline fields, setting blurOnSubmit to true means that pressing
>   return will blur the field and trigger the onSubmitEditing event
>   instead of inserting a newline into the field.

I'll try testing this.

**Edit:**
**Done testing**

blurOnSubmit doesn't work like it's supposed to in react-native 0.14.2. Even when set to true, the return/done button and enter key just create a newline and do not blur the field.

I'm not able to test this on newer versions at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try it! It works in the middle of the line also!

```
<TextInput
              placeholder={I18n.t('enterContactQuery')}

              value={this.state.query}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text, allowEditing: true })}

              selection = {this.state.selection}
              onSelectionChange={(event) => this.setState({ cursorPosition: event.nativeEvent.selection, selection: event.nativeEvent.selection, allowEditing: true })}
              onSubmitEditing={() => {
                const { query, cursorPosition } = this.state;
                let newText = query;
                const ar = newText.split('');
                ar.splice(cursorPosition.start, 0, '\n');
                newText = ar.join('');
                if (cursorPosition.start === query.length && query.endsWith('\n')) {
                  this.setState({ query: newText });
                } else if (this.state.allowEditing) {
                  this.setState({
                    query: newText,
                    selection: {
                      start: cursorPosition.start + 1,
                      end: cursorPosition.end + 1
                    },
                    allowEditing: !this.state.allowEditing
                  });
                }
              }}
              multiline = {true}
              numberOfLines = {10}
              blurOnSubmit={false}
              editable={true}
              // clearButtonMode="while-editing"
            />
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  query: '',
  cursorPosition: [0,0],
  selection: null,
  allowEditing: true
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```js
constructor () {
        super()
        this.state = {
            text : '',
            lastText : '',
            inputHeight:40
        }
    }




    writing(text){
        this.setState({
            text : text
        })
    }

    contentSizeChange(event){
        if(this.state.lastText.split("\n").length != this.state.text.split("\n").length){
            this.submitTextInput();
        }else{
            this.setState({
                inputHeight : event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height
            })
        }
    }


    submitTextInput(){
        Alert.alert('submit input  : ' + this.state.text);
        this.setState({
            text : ''
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>
                <TextInput
                    style={{height:this.state.inputHeight}}
                    multiline={true}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.writing(text)}
                    onContentSizeChange={(event) => this.contentSizeChange(event)}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => this.submitTextInput()}
                    value={this.state.text}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Care to provide some context? Wall of code answers are not very helpful